# gcloud auth configure-docker not working in windows

Tags: docker, gcloud

I am working in Windows & machine. I want to deploy my helloworld application in Kubernetes engine. I build the container image and tag it for uploading, I ran following command `docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-app:v1 .` and my docker image is created. After that when I run `gcloud auth configure-docker`
 I am getting bellow error.

[image: gcloud auth configure-docker]

My reference link
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug.

Please consider reporting it to Google's public issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102

Meanwhile, please try an alternative auth method:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud_as_a_docker_credential_helper